# Add paragraph element programmatically

Tags: 8, paragraphs

When change format field through ajax I want to add paragraph element programmatically and display it on current form, just do the same like if I would click the add question answer, any ideas ?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to do this with Javascript. You'll need to add a listener on the text format field and trigger a click on the button when the text format value is changed to what you want.